# i see some products in "category products" but in "manage products" page i don`t found that products?

Tags: magento-1.9, products-management

When i want to add new category i see some products in "category products" .
[image: category products in add new product page]

but in "manage products" page as you see i don`t found that products ??

[image: the all products in manage products page]

Comment: please reindex from index management

Answer (score 3):

This happens because not all products had a status or a visibility set or the stock.
In the product grid the collection is built like this (among others):

```
    if (Mage::helper('catalog')->isModuleEnabled('Mage_CatalogInventory')) {
        $collection->joinField('qty',
            'cataloginventory/stock_item',
            'qty',
            'product_id=entity_id',
            '{{table}}.stock_id=1',
            'left');
    }
    ....
    $collection->joinAttribute('status', 'catalog_product/status', 'entity_id', null, 'inner');
    $collection->joinAttribute('visibility', 'catalog_product/visibility', 'entity_id', null, 'inner');
```

All 3 joins are inner joins. So if there are no values in the joined table the rows are not returned.
Most probably some import has gone wrong, or it was not supposed to go right in the first place.
To check this, you have to edit one of the products that show up in the category but not in the grid.
Just edit one of the products that appear in the grid, then change the id in the url with one of the products that appear in the category. 30 for example.
Fill in the required fields and save. If the product new appears in the grid then that's the problem. You have to edit all of them and do the same.